# Multiple liveness probes in kuberenetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-health-check

I have a program which has multiple independent<sup>1</sup> components.

It is trivial to add a liveness probe in all of the components, however it's not easy to have a *single* liveness probe which would determine the health of all of the program's components.

How can I make kubernetes look at multiple liveness probes and restart the container when any of those are defunct?

I know it can be achieved by adding more software, for example an additional bash script which does the liveness checks, but I am looking for a native way to do this.

---

<sup>1</sup>By independent I mean that failure of one component does not make the other components fail.

Comment: Shouldnt they be running in different Pods or different containers within a Pod at the very least?

Comment: @user2983542 they should, however not all applications are well-designed.

Comment: Right, I don't think this is possible, although I stand to be corrected. How about creating a sidecar container with some logic and set the probe to that?

Comment: So if 1 of 3 of your components fail liveness probe, the pod should be 33% unavailable? Trying to express what you want to achieve would already give you a clue.

Answer (score 6):

The Kubernetes API allows one liveness and one readness per application (Deployment / POD). I recommend creating a validations centralizing service that has an endpoint rest:

```
livenessProbe:
  httpGet:
    path: /monitoring/alive
    port: 3401
    httpHeaders:
    - name: X-Custom-Header
      value: Awesome
  initialDelaySeconds: 15
  timeoutSeconds: 1
  periodSeconds: 15
```

or try one bash to same task, like:

```
livenessProbe:
  exec:
    command:
      - bin/bash
      - -c
      - ./liveness.sh
  initialDelaySeconds: 220
  timeoutSeconds: 5
```

liveness.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ $(ps -ef | grep java | wc -l) -ge 1 ]; then
  echo 0
else
  echo "Nothing happens!" 1>&2
    exit 1
fi
```

Recalling what the handling of messages can see in the events the failure in question:
"Warning Unhealthy Pod Liveness probe failed: Nothing happens!"

Hope this helps

Comment: More exactly, there is one probe per container (and there can be several containers per pod/deployment/daemonset). The container is restarted when it's liveness probe fails.  --  Thank's for the hint about the message! I did not understans this un the doc.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't do that. The model is pretty simple, one probe per container, follow the restart policy on failure.

Understood about the designed-for-containers problem with legacy apps, but there really are a lot of ways to arrange for resources to be shared for legacy compatibility. If the components of this system are already different processes, then there should be a way to partition them into containers.

If the components are threads or some other intra-application modularization technique, then the liveness determination really has to come from inside the app.

Answer (score 0):

For this case create custom script and handle multiple cases as per requirement and give single output for container as readiness response. Which will be considered to take final decision in the life cycle management of kubernetes