# How to put two ports in "livenessProbe"?

Tags: kubernetes, probe

My legacy server listens on two TCP ports. I want to put livenessProbe and readinessProbe on two ports. For single port it looks like the following. How to do it for 2 ports ?

```
livenessProbe:
  tcpSocket:
    port: 15772
  initialDelaySeconds: 10
  periodSeconds: 5
  failureThreshold: 5
readinessProbe:
  tcpSocket:
    port: 15772
initialDelaySeconds: 10
periodSeconds: 5
timeoutSeconds: 5
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple liveness probes in kuberenetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49172671/multiple-liveness-probes-in-kuberenetes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some paths to your goal.
If you own the project running in the container, you can define a http endpoint like /heathz or /ready with your logic to achieve this.
Otherwise, the project is a third-part one, you could write a shell to check ports like as follows:

healthcheck.sh

```bash
for port in 80 22
do nc -z localhost $port && echo "$port is up";
done
```

this shell will output (if 80 and 22 are listening):

```bash
80 is up
22 is up
```

and then, use exec probe:

```yaml
livenessProbe:
      exec:
        command:
        - /path/to/healthcheck.sh
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes pod object will not allow to keep more than one liveness and readiness probe per container. if the pod contains multiple containers, you can define multiple liveness/readiness probes for every containers.